# C# Agenda de Compromissos

Tags: c#

Preciso fazer uma agenda que vai receber alguns compromissos, e no dia desse compromisso ela vai enviar um aviso. 
Alguém pode me indicar algum material, ou caminho que eu precise começar?

Comment: Que tipo de agenda? Tem algum exemplo?

Comment: Vai ser em Forms? Web? O que você vai usar?

Comment: Vo usar forms , assim , eu tenho a agenda e por exemplo , na segunda feira , eu tenho tal compromisso , outrotal compromisso e no dia que forem estes compromissos ele avisa . A parte de avisar eu vou fazer por email , já tenho pronto , era mais a parte de gravar e tal :D

Comment: Pesquise no Google sobre C# CRUD (Create, Read, Update e Delete), são as funções básicas para vc poder inserir, ler, atualizar e excluir os registro de sua agenda. Existem diversos artigos sobre e videos no youtube.

Comment: Obrigado ! Já estou finalizando

Comment: Você pode usar a API de agenda do office 365 como fonte de inspiração:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations